# SearchView with custom ListView and custom Adaptor

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, searchview

I want to use the SearchView widget to filter Data.
The filtering doesnt work since i switched to a custom layout for the Listview. The ListView gets filled with all Songs i have but then doesnt update when something gets typed into the SearchView. I just want to get SearchView working for Custom ListView. If u have any Helpful Links pls share them with me.

Search Class:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import univie.g02.t06.tmsd.dummydata.DummyAPIData;
import univie.g02.t06.tmsd.dummydata.DummySong;
import univie.g02.t06.tmsd.MyAdapter;

public class Search extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listV;
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<DummySong> listSongs = new ArrayList<DummySong>();
    MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        listV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

        listSongs = DummyAPIData.getAllDummySongs();
        for (int i = 0; i < listSongs.size(); i++) {
            listItems.add(listSongs.get(i).getDummyArtistTitle());
            titles.add(listSongs.get(i).getDummyTitle());
        }
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                listItems);
        listV.setAdapter(adapter);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                listV.setAdapter(adapter);

                return true;

            }

            @Override
            public  boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query){

                return true;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

MyAdapter Class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {
    private List<String> list;
    ArrayList<String> origData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resources, ArrayList<String> list) {
        super(context, resources, list);
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        this.origData = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return list.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return 0;
        //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);
        }

        //Handle TextView and display string from your list
        TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
        listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
                list.remove(position); //or some other task
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

customlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="add" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activitysearch.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="univie.g02.t06.tmsd.Search">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/search_view" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, SearchView doesn't support any adapter other than CursorAdapter. I would recommend to create a custom layout and load to achieve the same results.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SearchView searchView  =(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            adapterQuote.getFilter().filter(s);
            listView.setAdapter(adapterQuote);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapterQuote.getFilter().filter(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Comment: I think this enough to this problem. And some way you can create a editext with a button to search and get text from editext and display it with list.getyourStringValue.contain("String")